# ArrayList в Bundle

Tags: android, массивы

Добрый день. Существует ArrayList вида

```
ArrayList<People> people = new ArrayList<People>();
```

Нужно через Bundle передать этот типизированный массив в Fragment1. Как это сделать? И как принять такой массив во Fragment1? Сама суть передачи данных между Activity и Fragment ясна:

```
Fragment1 f = new Fragment1();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
// Но это не число и не строка) ArrayList<People> people
args.putInt("index", index);
f.setArguments(args);
return f;
```

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Может, проще получать этот лист в фрагменте?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class People implements Parcelable {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;

    //setters and getters
    ...

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    private People (Parcel in) {
        setFirstName(in.readString());
        setLastName(in.readString());

        setAge(in.readInt());
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(getFirstName);
        dest.writeString(getLastName);

        dest.writeInt(getAge);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<People> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<People >() {

        @Override
        public People createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new People (source);
        }

        @Override
        public People[] newArray(int size) {
            return new People[size];
        }
    };
}
```

---

```
ArrayList<People> people;  
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putParcelableArrayList("people", people)
```

Comment: Намного проще вместо Parcelable имплементить Serializable. Serializable - флаговый интерфейс, который не имеет методов. Используя этот интерфейс, вы сообщаете, что объект класса, реализующего данный интерфейс, может быть сериализован стандартным образом.

Comment: @metalurgus, http://habrahabr.ru/post/173975/

Answer (score 1):

[putParcelableArrayList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putParcelableArrayList%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3C?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E%29). Для его использования надо реализовать интерфейс `Parcelable` у вашего класса `People`.

Comment: Пожалуйста, можно пример кода. Мне говорили про Parcelable, но я не смог им воспользоваться.