# Widget Android передача данных между классами

Tags: android, виджет, android-widgets, storage

Есть список списков(ArrayList>) в нем хранятся данные, которые я должен вывести на сам виджет. Получаются они скачиванием из интернета HTML-док. и его парсингом. Для каждого виджета свой такой список, каким образом мне его передавать между классами? Просто как переменную? Или через Bundle|Parcelable. В общем, нужен дельный совет.

Comment: Чего-то Ваш вопрос вызвал у меня мысль: а не проще ли загружать данные во второй активности, обычно, передача массивов это немного ппоблемно (ну или, как минимум, не красиво смотрится в коде :)). Ну а раз уж передавать: или в цикле через `Bundle` и тд, или свой `Bundle` для `ArrayList` делать.

Comment: @bukashka101 Как я понял, чтобы передавать через Bundle куском придется писать что-то типа `public class MyList extends ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> implements Parselable {..}` А это из этого следует еще и переделка парсера \ написание к нему адаптера. Еще я не очень понимаю как это написать. А точнее, если свой ArrayList делать, то еще один класс придется писать - `public class MyInnerList extends ArrayList<String> implements Parselable {..}` А тот делать как Список объектов MyInnerList?

Comment: Как-то вы слишком сложно все расписали... Честно говоря, никогда не пользовался таким методом, но примерно такая же задача, но с другим типом данных у меня была (понял, что контексты лучше не передавать и как-то ушел от этого), но, когда задавал вопрос тут, мне дали ссылку по костомизации `Bundle`. На stackoverflow рассматривается конкретно Ваша проблема с `ArrayList()`, вот — http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/366515/arraylist-%D0%B2-bundle Думаю тут Вы ответите на все свои вопросы :).